# Batch tag creation in enterprise architect with javascript

Tags: javascript, enterprise-architect, requirements

I've created a EA project with a bunch of requirements, that needs to be imported into Redmine. Instead of doing it by hand, We want to use a tool
This tool needs to use some specific tag for sync data, so I need to create five tags for every requirement, and I simply cannot do it for every requirement since I've hundreds of them.

I've starting to check the javascript scripting, and I've noticed a function like this one in one example:

```
/**
 * Sets the specified TaggedValue on the provided element. If the provided element does not already
 * contain a TaggedValue with the specified name, a new TaggedValue is created with the requested
 * name and value. If a TaggedValue already exists with the specified name then action to take is
 * determined by the replaceExisting variable. If replaceExisting is set to true, the existing value
 * is replaced with the specified value, if not, a new TaggedValue is created with the new value.
 *
 * @param[in] theElement (EA.Element) The element to set the TaggedValue value on
 * @param[in] taggedValueName (String) The name of the TaggedValue to set
 * @param[in] taggedValueValue (variant) The value of the TaggedValue to set
 * @param[in] replaceExisting (boolean) If a TaggedValue of the same name already exists, specifies 
 * whether to replace it, or create a new TaggedValue.
 */
function TVSetElementTaggedValue( theElement /* : EA.Element */, taggedValueName /* : String */, taggedValueValue /* : variant */, replaceExisting /* : boolean */ ) /* : void */
{
    if ( theElement != null && taggedValueName.length > 0 )
    {
        var taggedValue as EA.TaggedValue;
        taggedValue = null;

        // If replace existing was specified then attempt to get a tagged value from the element
        // with the provided name
        if ( replaceExisting )
            taggedValue = theElement.TaggedValues.GetByName( taggedValueName );

        if ( taggedValue == null )
        {
            taggedValue = theElement.TaggedValues.AddNew( taggedValueName, taggedValueValue );
        }
        else
        {
            taggedValue.Value = taggedValueValue;
        }

        taggedValue.Update();
    }
}
```

What I need to do is how to retrieve a list of requirements that are stored in a specific package, and how to cycle them in order to apply this function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically:

```
for e in myPackage.elements:
    if e.type == 9: #code for Requirement
        print(e.name)
        for t in e.taggedValues:
            print(t.name, t.value, t.notes)
```

will list the element of the package and all their tagged values.

This it Python, but it's not difficult to translate to any other language.